# Why are there two "GTO TWIN TURBO" cars?

Tags: gran-turismo-3-a-spec

In Gran Turismo 3, there are two separate Mitsubishi "GTO TWIN TURBO" cars available to purchase.  They have exactly the same price, the same engine, and almost all of the specs are identical.  Besides having different graphics in the list, one is 25mm longer, 30kg lighter, and is available in green rather than blue.

Is there something I'm missing, or are these really nearly identical?  Is there any advantage whatsoever of the heavier car?

EDIT: I just noticed that another Mitsubishi car has a double.  There are two "LANCER EVOLUTION VI GSR Tommi Makinen Edition" cars which are identical in all listed specifications.

Comment: I think this is a 'why did they design the game that way...' kind of question, off topic.

Comment: @Ender Unless there is some kind of in-game advantage to having two, or some secret difference.

Answer (score 1):

Finally a question I happen to know the answer to. I was/am obsessed with this car, ever since GT funnily enough, and have seriously considered buying one just because of this.

Anyway back on topic there is a slight, rather very slight, performance difference between the two. The lighter one is ever so slightly better. However there are two simply so you can own two, vary their setup/look etc. for a slightly different experience.

Hope that helps.